# Oracle APEX RDS Tabs on multiple rows instead of scroll

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there any way to have tabs show as sets of rows, rather than 'scrolling' through them?

For instance, If I have my app split into two regions, with data on the left, and sections of meta-data on the right, if I have more than 4 tabs on the right, it starts to scroll.  I'd like to be able to have them on multiple rows.  Sort of like:

```
Section 1           |      Section 2
Main data area      |  Tab 1 |  Tab 2  |  Tab 3
                    |  Tab 4 |  Tab 5  |
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What type of region are your sections? How structured is your page? Give us some screenshots or create an application to illustrate your problem and give us access to it

Comment: Are you still looking for help on this? If so, could you please provide more details? Why use tabs at all for this UI? Have a look at the Scrollspy component of Boostrap here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/scrollspy/ Maybe something like that would work better.